# How can I cache videos in React Native

Tags: react-native, caching, video

It is already long time that I struggle and can't find a proper solution to this question: how handle video cache in RN. I am using react-native-video to show the videos, but that package does not have cache option yet. Please help to find a solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

David's answer is good but you will need to go into `node_modules/react-native-cached-image/utils/pathUtils.js` and edit `defaultImageTypes` array to include `mp4` or whatever file extension you want to save. If you don't do this then the video files will be saved as JPG and cause the `Video` component to crash.

There doesn't seem to be a way to override the accepted file types without directly modifying the core `cached-image` module. Also you'll want to make sure to check the `loaded` state property before trying to load the video because it will crash for that as well. After you do that it will work!

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a solution here. So the magic is in `ImageCacheManager`, which now can be used to cache any type of file, e.g. video files or pdf files. So I used the following package `https://github.com/kernelnetworks/react-native-cached-image.git`, where all proper changes are done to be able to cache any type of files.

```js
...
import { ImageCacheManager } from "react-native-cached-image";
import Video from "react-native-video";
...
    // inside class based component
    componentDidMount() {
       ImageCacheManager({})
        .downloadAndCacheUrl(this.props.source.uri)
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({ cachedVideoURI: res, loaded: true });
        })
        .catch(err => {
         ...
        });
    }
```

And then use that cached uri as a source for your video (or for any other type of file).

```js
<Video source={{uri: this.state.cachedVideoURI}}
```

That's it !!!
Hope this will help someone to save bunch of times

Comment: This was an awesome solution and deserves more exposure for how to cache videos in React Native. Most other solutions are super complicated and involve doing what is already being done for you in this react-native-cache-image package. You must also implement @NathanCorbin 's comment about adding mp4 to the default file.